# can not getting the data from if condtion ROS ardunio

Tags: arduino, callback, ros

I have a node running on pc which published [std_msgs/String] in string It published M, R, S, I have the following Arduino code.

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void messageCb( const std_msgs::String & toggle_msg)
{
nh.loginfo("recived new message ");
nh.loginfo(toggle_msg.data);

if(toggle_msg.data == "M")
{  
nh.loginfo("Recived M if-statment ");  
}

else if(toggle_msg.data == "R")
{  
nh.loginfo("Recived R if-statment ");  
}

else if(toggle_msg.data == "S")
{  
nh.loginfo("Recived S if-statment ");  
}
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::String> sub("talker_vision", &messageCb );

void setup()
{ 
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop()
{  
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

I received M , R , S from `nh.loginfo(toggle_msg.data);` but when I applied If condition

```
if(toggle_msg.data == "M")
{  
nh.loginfo("Recived M if-statment ");  
}
```

there is no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are comparing two strings here which are defined as `char*`, not the Arduino classic `String` type is used. You can see the type of the string inside the message [which was generated for example here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/blob/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3_ros_lib/std_msgs/String.h#L15).

Comparing

```
const char* str1 = "abc";
const char* str2 = "abc";
bool equal = str1 == str2;
```

will be always false since you are comparing memory positions and not the string itself.

So you have two options:

Create two Arduino string objects and compare them

```
String arduinoString1 = String(str1);
String arduinoString2 = String(str2);
bool equal = arduinoString1 == arduinoString2;
```

Or even better **is to use the standard string comparision `strcmp`** ([documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)) function as [described here for example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/strcmp-in-c-cplusplus#:%7E:text=It%20compares%20strings%20lexicographically%20which,or%20NULL%20character%20is%20found.):

```
bool equal = strcmp(str1, str2) == 0;
```